# How can I change a functions ABI based on the target operating system?

Tags: rust, abi

I am writing a cross-platform library in Rust where I need to use specific ABI strings for Windows and Unix. My current solution is:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! create_plugin {
    (@internal $name:ident) => {
        #[no_mangle]
        #[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
        pub unsafe extern "stdcall" fn Test(data: *const *const u32) -> bool {
            // Source 1
        }

        #[no_mangle]
        #[cfg(not(target_os = "windows"))]
        pub unsafe extern "C" fn Test(data: *const *const u32) -> bool {
            // Source 1 (duplicate)
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Is there any way to reduce the copy-and-pasted code in definitions?

Comment: Why do you need your Windows version to be stdcall? You can just use cdecl (i.e. "C") in 32-bit without issues if the C-side declaration matches. And under 64-bit, stdcall doesn't do anything anymore.

Comment: It’s a 32bit binary and I have no acces to source code. It expecting stdcall and crashes on cdecl.

Comment: So you're writing a plugin for an existing program?

Comment: Yes, it’s plugin for existing program

Comment: TL;DR: more macros.

Comment: @Shepmaster funny, but not clean.

Comment: @xakdog no humor intended — macros are a primary solution to avoid repetition when existing abstractions aren't powerful enough.

Comment: @Shepmaster finally I found a `"system"` convention that will interpreted as "stdcall" on win32 https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/ffi.html#foreign-calling-conventions  May be it's not an duplicate?